# How to create two different version of codes for flavor variants

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-flavors

I want to create 2 versions of `Fragment` for different build variant, like whole code gonna be different in flavor 1 than in flavor 2. I wanna solve this without doing if-else based on `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` parameter in code. That means if I have `MapFragment`, I want to have exact same class named `MapFragment` with different code when different flavor is built. Reason why I want to do it is that I don't want to have any reference to this `MapFragment` from other version(flavor
in any logs or specifics on my App. This should work similarly like `string.xml` localization is working or `dimens.xml`. Is there any way how to achieve it?

Reason for this is that I'm using Huawei map and `ag-connect` services and also Google Play map. Problem is that Huawei is using some background location service which is then rejecting my app on Google Play. This Huawei flavor should never be available on Google Play, it is like standalone copy of App for Huawei Shop.

That means if I build `.apk` from Google Play (flavor 1), I will not include any ag-connect services or classes or references/imports from Huawei flavor and vice-versa.

UPDATE:

As I checked comment below, I tried to create sourceSets and reimplement my flavors to those new sets. But it still cant compile.

Also I need to know how to combine those flavors with types and sources. Because I have 2 main sources: google and huawei. Then I need 4 flavors for each of these sources like googleProd, googleProdTest, googleDev, googleDevTest and same for huawei and also all of those should have build type debug/release in case I want to release them to Google Play store for testing. Problem is that I need something like product subflavors. Each huawei flavor (prod, test, dev, dev-test) will use huawei sourceSet (main+huawei) and each google flavor (prod, test, dev, dev-test) will use google sourceSet(main+google). That means main sources will be code which is common for both and google/huawei sources has different version of same Fragment.

So these should be final buildVariants:

1. googleProd (main+google src)
2. googleTest (main+google src)
3. googleDev (main+google src)
4. googleDevTest (main+google src)
5. huaweiProd (main+huawei src)
6. huaweiTest (main+huawei src)
7. huaweiDev (main+huawei src)
8. huaweiDevTest (main+huawei src)

and release/debug build type for all 8. So total of 16 variants.

That means I need to know how to merge `google` src with `prod`, `test`, `dev` and `dev-test` flavors and `huawei` src with `huaweiProd`, `huaweiTest`, `huaweiDev` and `huaweiDev-test` flavors so I dont need to have 4 huawei Fragments which are identical and 4 google fragments which are identical for all flavors. It should work like abstract class/parent class.

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
No signature of method: build_1t7zaa85nxlbgjo4n3n9fcb4s.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1t7zaa85nxlbgjo4n3n9fcb4s$_run_closure1) values: [build_1t7zaa85nxlbgjo4n3n9fcb4s$_run_closure1@56b08118]
```

Code Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//Google Crashlytics
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//Google Services
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//Kotlin
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    def code = getVersionCodeTimestamp()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "----"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode code
        versionName "2.5.5"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        app{
           ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.app
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"false"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.app
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        google {
            java.srcDirs('src/main/java', 'src/google/java')
        }
        huawei {
            java.srcDirs('src/main/java', 'src/hua/java')
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "production"
    productFlavors {
        google {
            prod {
                dimension "production"
                ...
            }
            test {
                dimension "production"
                ...
            }
            dev {
                ...
            }
            dev_test {
                ...
            }
        }

        huawei {
            prod {
                dimension "production"
                ...
            }
            test {
                dimension "production"
                ...
            }
            dev {
                ...
            }
            dev_test {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':pin')
    //Kotlin SDK
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.8'

    //AndroidX
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0'

    //Google SDK
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'

    //Google Crashlytics SDK
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //Google Analytics SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'

    //Google Firebase Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'

    //Huawei SDK
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:identity:4.0.1.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.3.303'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:4.0.1.301'
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?